# (gedit:3378): Gtk-WARNING **: 18:50:39.593: cannot open display:

Tags: software-installation

I can't seem to get the following code running

sudo gedit .bashrc

I always get the error
(gedit:3378): Gtk-WARNING **: 18:50:39.593: cannot open display:

May I know how I can solve this issue? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In your `~/.bashrc`, set the `EDITOR` and `VISUAL` environment variables to your preferred editor.

```
export EDITOR=$(type -p gedit)
export VISUAL=$(type -p gedit)
```

After `source ~/.bashrc`, you can:

```
sudoedit .bashrc
```

Read `man sudoedit`.

`sudoedit` uses your `sudo` access to make a temporary copy of the restricted file, owned by you, then invokes `$EDITOR` on that temporary file. If `$EDITOR` returns success, `sudoedit` uses your `sudo` access to copy the temporary file back to the restricted file.

Your way fails because your display, either X Server or Wayland, is configured to reject connections from non-you UIDs. `root` (`UID 0`) is not you.